# Can powershell combine data from multiple rows into one row and then "split" the data below that row for multiple "key" values

Tags: powershell, csv, quickbooks

I'm trying to take some data from a billing system that doesn't have an API and sends us files in Excel format and map the data into new columns and headers to match up with Quickbooks fields.

I am about halfway there, I have the split data all mapped to the correct columns and rows, but I can't figure out how to combine the data into one row for each account above all the split data.

Here is how the data comes from the billing program:

```
BillingDate,Type,Acct,Customer,Code,Description,Qty,Price,Extension,GLCode
8/1/19,MRC,1003,Test Account,CONF6,CONFERENCE CALL RATE - $0.06/CPM/LEG,1,0.00,0.00,4202
8/1/19,MRC,1003,Test Account,INTL,INTERNATIONAL RATE PLAN,1,0.00,0.00,4202
8/1/19,MRC,1003,Test Account,MASU,MASS ANNOUNCEMENT,1,0.00,0.00,4202
8/1/19,MRC,1003,Test Account,UNLD,UNLIMITED LONG DISTANCE,1,0.00,0.00,4202
8/1/19,MRC,1003,Test Account,W911,911 SERVICE,1,0.00,0.00,4202
8/1/19,MRC,1003,Test Account,WDA,DIRECTORY ASSISTANCE,1,0.00,0.00,4202
8/1/19,MRC,1003,Test Account,WDIDNN,DID NUMBERS - NATIONAL,42,0.00,0.00,4202
8/1/19,MRC,1003,Test Account,WIPTL1,SIP TRUNK,1,375.00,375.00,4202
8/1/19,MRC,1003,Test Account,WMGRT,MANAGED ROUTER,1,50.00,50.00,4202
8/1/19,Prorates,1003,Test Account,WIPTL1,SIP TRUNK,1,362.90,362.90,4202
8/1/19,Prorates,1003,Test Account,WMGRT,MANAGED ROUTER,1,48.39,48.39,4202
8/1/19,Tax Detail,1003,Test Account,00-59,FCC Cost Recovery Fee,1,1.43,1.43,3400
8/1/19,Tax Detail,1003,Test Account,00-60,Federal Telecommunications Relay Services Fund,1,13.44,13.44,3400
8/1/19,Tax Detail,1003,Test Account,00-R1,Federal Recovery Fee V001-002,1,103.31,103.31,3400
8/1/19,Tax Detail,1003,Test Account,01-01,State Sales Tax - Intrastate Telecom,1,30.47,30.47,3410
8/1/19,Tax Detail,1003,Test Account,02-02,County Sales Tax,1,5.41,5.41,3410
8/1/19,Tax Detail,1003,Test Account,02-33,911 Surcharge (Local),1,5.00,5.00,3400
```

Below is my current PS Script:

```
$path = "pathtofile"
$DataFile = $path + "source.csv"
$ExportedFileCSV = $path + "final.csv"

$dataInput = Import-Csv $DataFile
$dataOutput = Import-Csv $ExportedFileCSV

$dataInput | ForEach-Object {

    $newData = $_
    $newRecordProperties = [ordered]@{
        "TRNS"="TRNS",$newData.null,"INVOICE",$newData.BillingDate
        "SPL"="SPL"
        "SPLID"=$newData.null
        "TRNSTYPE"="INVOICE"
        "DATE"=$newData.BillingDate
        "NAME"=$newData.Customer
        "DOCNUM"=$newData.null
        "DUEDATE"=$newdata.null
        "ACCNT"=$newData.GLCode
        "AMOUNT"=-$newData.Price
        "EXTRA"=-$newData.Extension
    }
    $newRecord = new-object psobject -Property $newRecordProperties
    Write-Output $newRecord
} | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," | % {$_ -replace '"',''} | Out-File $ExportedFileCSV
```

I expect the output to look like the following:

```
!TRNS,TRNSID,TRNSTYPE,DATE,NAME,DOCNUM,DUEDATE,ACCNT,AMOUNT,PAID
!SPL,SPLID,TRNSTYPE,DATE,NAME,DOCNUM,DUEDATE,ACCNT,AMOUNT,EXTRA
!ENDTRNS,,,,,,,,,
TRNS,,INVOICE,08/01/2019,Test Account,080119-1003,08/01/2019,1200,995.35,N
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,4202,-375.00
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,4202,-50.00
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,4202,-362.90
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,4202,-48.39
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,3400,-1.43
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,3400,-13.44
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,3400,-103.31
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,3410,-30.47
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,3410,-5.41
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,3400,-5.00
SPL,,INVOICE,,,,,,0.00,AUTOSTAX
ENDTRNS,,,,,,,,,
```

Instead this is what I get:

```
SPL,SPLID,TRNSTYPE,DATE,NAME,DOCNUM,DUEDATE,ACCNT,AMOUNT,EXTRA
SPL,,INVOICE,8/1/19,Test Account,,,,-375,-375
SPL,,INVOICE,8/1/19,Test Account,,,,-50,-50
SPL,,INVOICE,8/1/19,Test Account,,,,-362.9,-362.9
SPL,,INVOICE,8/1/19,Test Account,,,,-48.39,-48.39
SPL,,INVOICE,8/1/19,Test Account,,,,-1.43,-1.43
SPL,,INVOICE,8/1/19,Test Account,,,,-13.44,-13.44
SPL,,INVOICE,8/1/19,Test Account,,,,-103.31,-103.31
SPL,,INVOICE,8/1/19,Test Account,,,,-30.47,-30.47
SPL,,INVOICE,8/1/19,Test Account,,,,-5.41,-5.41
SPL,,INVOICE,8/1/19,Test Account,,,,-5,-5
```

I've been working on it for about 2 weeks and granted, I'm new to Powershell. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: could you post a sample of the input?

Comment: @swestner sure! sorry I should have included that in the post. I've edited the post to include that now.

Comment: @mklement0 my apologies, that was some leftovers from things I was trying. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From having a little read around about QuickBooks just now, it looks like your desired output file is a "Quickbooks Multi-Line Transaction Csv" file in the following format:

```
!File Header 1
!File Header 2
!File Header 3
TRNS Record
SPL Record 1 
SPL Record 2
... etc ...
SPL Record N
SPL Tax Record
ENDTRNS Record
```

If we break it down we can just write out each section in turn to produce the desired output file. First off, though, we're going to need a little helper function to generate the csv lines because the default `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet always includes the header row, which we don't want so we'll strip it off.

```bsh
function ConvertTo-CsvRow
{
    param( $InputObject )
    # convert the input object into a csv record and remove the header line
    return ConvertTo-Csv -InputObject $InputObject -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," `
        | Select-Object -Skip 1 `
        | % { $_ -replace '"','' };
}
```

Then, we'll read the input file and process it a little bit:

```bsh
$splits = Import-Csv $DataFile
foreach( $split in $splits )
{
    # convert some strings into the appropriate types
    $split.BillingDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($split.BillingDate, "d/M/yy", $null);
    $split.Price       = [decimal]::Parse($split.Price);
}
# remove lines with zero value
$splits = $splits | where-object { $_.Price -ne 0 };
```

**File Headers**

We'll just write these out to the file as as literal strings:

```bsh
# write file headers
Set-Content -Path $exportFile -Value "!TRNS,TRNSID,TRNSTYPE,DATE,NAME,DOCNUM,DUEDATE,ACCNT,AMOUNT,PAID";
Add-Content -Path $exportFile -Value "!SPL,SPLID,TRNSTYPE,DATE,NAME,DOCNUM,DUEDATE,ACCNT,AMOUNT,EXTRA";
Add-Content -Path $exportFile -Value "!ENDTRNS,,,,,,,,,";
```

**TRNS Record**

This row contains some summary figures - we're going to assume some of them can be taken from the first split in the input file, and the `AMOUNT` needs to be calculated by adding up the `Price` from all the split records:

```bsh
# write TRNS header
$split0 = $splits[0];
$trns = new-object PSObject -Property ([ordered] @{
    "TRNS"     = "TRNS"
    "TRNSID"   = $null
    "TRNSTYPE" = "INVOICE"
    "DATE"     = $split0.BillingDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    "NAME"     = $split0.Customer
    "DOCNUM"   = $split0.BillingDate.ToString("ddMMyy") + "-" + $split0.Acct
    "DUEDATE"  = $split0.BillingDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    "ACCNT"    = 1200
    "AMOUNT"   = ($splits | Measure-Object "Price" -Sum | Select-Object -Expand "Sum").ToString("F")
    "PAID"     = "N"
})
$trnsCsv = ConvertTo-CsvRow -InputObject $trns;
Add-Content -Path $exportFile -Value $trnsCsv;
```

**SPL Records**

We just need to loop through each input record more or less like your original code, but with some output formatting applied for date formats and decimal places:

```bsh
# write splits
foreach( $split in $splits )
{
   $spl = new-object PSObject -Property ([ordered] @{
        "SPL"      = "SPL"
        "SPLID"    = $null
        "TRNSTYPE" = "INVOICE"
        "DATE"     = $null
        "NAME"     = $null
        "DOCNUM"   = $null
        "DUEDATE"  = $null
        "ACCNT"    = $split.GLCode
        "AMOUNT"   = (-$split.Price).ToString("F")
    });
    $splCsv = ConvertTo-CsvRow -InputObject $spl;
    Add-Content -Path $exportFile -Value $splCsv;
};
```

**SPL Tax Record**

I don't know if I've interpreted this properly, so it might not even be needed in all cases, and it might have to be calculated from the splits in the input file, but the code below produces your desired output file:

```bsh
# write SPL tax record
$spl = new-object PSObject -Property ([ordered] @{
    "SPL"      = "SPL"
    "SPLID"    = $null
    "TRNSTYPE" = "INVOICE"
    "DATE"     = $null
    "NAME"     = $null
    "DOCNUM"   = $null
    "DUEDATE"  = $null
    "ACCNT"    = $null
    "AMOUNT"   = ([decimal] 0).ToString("F")
    "EXTRA"    = "AUTOSTAX"
})
$splCsv = ConvertTo-CsvRow -InputObject $spl;
Add-Content -Path $exportFile -Value $splCsv;
```

**ENDTRNS Footer**

Finally, the ENDTRNS footer...

```bsh
# write ENDTRNS footer
$endtrns = new-object PSObject -Property ([ordered] @{
    "ENDTRNS" = "ENDTRNS"
    "empty1"  = $null
    "empty2"  = $null
    "empty3"  = $null
    "empty4"  = $null
    "empty5"  = $null
    "empty6"  = $null
    "empty7"  = $null
    "empty8"  = $null
    "empty9"  = $null
})
$endtrnsCsv = ConvertTo-CsvRow -InputObject $endtrns;
Add-Content -Path $exportFile -Value $endtrnsCsv;
```

If you run all of these code blocks one after the other you should find it generates the exact byte-for-byte desired output file. There's probably a performance penalty in calling `ConvertTo-Csv` for each row but we're basically abusing it to generate one row of the output csv file at a time.

Note the above might need modifications if you're expecting multiple `TRNS ... ENDTRNS` in your input - you'll need to group your split records somehow and write each group into a separate `TRNS ... ENDTRNS` section.

Hope this helps..

M

Comment: This is incredible. I'm going to look at this tomorrow but it looks exactly like what I was going for! You got any kind of donation page or anything? Would love to send you a coffee/beer for all your help.

Comment: @JonathanReynolds - I appreciate the offer, but no need for that, and I don't have a donation page anyway! It's good enough practice for me to write code and explanations so that other people can understand them :-).

Comment: Worked great mate! Marked as answer, thank you 1000x for all your help and generosity.